# How can I convert Yahoo Ticker Symbols into ISIN Codes?

Tags: market-data, finance, yahoo, yahoofinance, codes

I have a list of all Yahoo Ticker Symbols and I want to convert them into ISIN Codes. I have been researching and found out that `finance.yahoo` in the US does not offer ISIN Codes, however, in Germany and UK the website does offer ISIN codes so basically I have half of the list with ISIN and the other half without. Most of the ones I am missing are from US Markets, and looking at the Ticker it is not really the Symbol but a code that uniquely identifies the Security/Stock in **Yahoo**, but not always other financial websites. This means:

- I may enter the Ticker in another financial website which contains the ISIN as well. In some cases, the Ticker may be the same as the Symbol of that specific site and I get the correct ISIN, however, in other cases it is not the same and it provides other ISIN which is not the one that matches the Yahoo Ticker. If I scrape other financial websites, there is a 50/50 chance of getting the correct ISIN for the Yahoo Ticker.
- On the other hand, if I go through all the Yahoo Ticker Symbols manually I would have to go over more than 10 000 which is highly inefficient and would take too much time, and eventually this would as well give small errors given to perhaps wrong copying/pasting of the Ticker, etc.

Is there a way to get the exact ISIN for Yahoo Ticker Symbols using perhaps some sort of programming language? Maybe Yahoo Developer Network?

I have found this [forum](https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Is-it-possible-to-map-a/1350645667194-a804b619-912b-4cd0-a38d-d2f286edef91/) which posted a similar question to mine and uses YQL, but somehow the method applied is deprecated or simply does not work for me, with any of the Symbols I enter. The question was posted almost 3 years ago and `yahoo.finance` may have change until now.

King Regards!!